# How to add tags to a to do list

Tags: swift, xcode, tags

I’m trying to create a to do app with a tag sorting system where the user can create tags to categorise the ‘to-dos’. I’ve been racking my brain with how to implement this. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is way to broad, we can't design the app for you. Besides, you should be able to find many tutorials that covers to-do lists online.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ENUM. This is just a rough answer and one of many solutions. You could also use a OptionSet if each todo needs multiple tags.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset

```
enum Tag {
case finished, pending, draft
}

struct ToDoNote {

var status : Tag
var task : String?
var user : User
}
```

Comment: Wow, i hadn’t heard of option sets, they look perfect. Do you know if there’s a way to add options to the option set during run time. I.e the user adds them

Comment: I don't think you can make it dynamic because these work with bit manipulation but I might just not know, that's a good question.